# Making a table look nicer

Tags: tables

I have this table with the following codes:

```
Table \ref{tab:2} lists all the variables in the model:
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Variable Descriptions}
\label{tab:2}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
Variables & Descriptions\\\hline
\textit{ln(wage)} & log of wage\\
\textit{educ} & years of education\\
\textit{black} & 1 if black and 0 if not\\
\textit{hisp} & 1 if hispanic and 0 if not\\
\textit{exper} & years of experience\\
\textit{exper$^{2}$} & years of experience squared\\
\textit{married} & 1 if married and 0 if not\\
\textit{union} & 1 if belongs to a union and 0 if not\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I was wondering if a nicer and a more professional-looking table is possible.

This is what I have in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}

% Packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dcolumn,caption}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
%% define a few struts
%% (from code by Claudio Beccari in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993)
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.9ex}}       % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % "bottom" strut
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
    \rel@kern{0.8}%
    \overline{\rel@kern{-0.8}\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.2}}%
    \rel@kern{-0.2}%
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
  \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{;}{,}{,}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{labelfont=normalfont,
              labelsep=colon}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\makeatletter
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{1}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \edef\@toclevel{\ifnum#2=\@m 0\else\number#2\fi}%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \let\@secnumber\@empty
  \else \@xp\let\@xp\@secnumber\csname the#1\endcsname\fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \edef\@secnumpunct{%
      \ifdim\@tempskipa>\z@ % not a run-in section heading
        \@ifnotempty{#8}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \else
        \@ifempty{#8}{.}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \fi
    }%
    \@ifempty{#8}{%
      \ifnum #2=\tw@ \def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}\fi}{}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{%
      \ifnum#2<\@m
        \@ifundefined{#1name}{}{%
          \ignorespaces\csname #1name\endcsname\space
        }%
      \fi
      \@seccntformat{#1}%
    }%
  \fi
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@ % then this is not a run-in section heading
    \begingroup #6\relax
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}{\interlinepenalty\@M #8\par}%
    \endgroup
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  \else
  \def\@svsechd{#6\hskip #3\@svsec
    \@ifnotempty{#8}{\ignorespaces#8\unskip
       %\@addpunct.
       }%
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  }%
  \fi
  \global\@nobreaktrue
  \@xsect{#5}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{plain}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{12pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
% Commenting/debugging
\let\IG\iffalse
\let\ENDIG\fi

%% Shortcuts
\newcommand{\td}[2]{\dfrac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand{\std}[2]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\ctd}[3]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d #2 d #3}}

\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\spd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\cpd}[3]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2 \partial #3}}

\newcommand{\pdi}[2]{\partial #1/\partial #2}

\newcommand{\LR}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Lg}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\half}{\tfrac{1}{2}}
\newcommand{\eqp}{\phantom{=}}
\newcommand{\eqs}{\buildrel s \over =}
\newcommand{\me}{\mathrm{e}}
%begin codes for footnotes (symbols)
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myfnsymbolsingle}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \ifcase#1% 0
    \or % 1
      \dagger%   
    \or % 2
      1 
    \or % 3  
      2
    \or % 4   
      3
    \or % 5
      4
    \else % >= 6
      \@ctrerr  
    \fi
  }%   
}   
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myfnsymbol}[1]{%
  \myfnsymbolsingle{\value{#1}}%
}

% remove upper boundary by multiplying the symbols if needed
\usepackage{alphalph}
\newalphalph{\myfnsymbolmult}[mult]{\myfnsymbolsingle}{}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{%
  \myfnsymbolmult{\value{footnote}}%
}
%end codes for footnotes (symbols)
```

Comment: Check out this

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples

Comment: Always post a ***complete*** small document. That is much more useful than a mere fragment.

Comment: Look for answers involving the `booktabs` package. One nice example, close to yours is [Vertical table lines are discontinuous with booktabs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172816/2693).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`booktabs` is recommended. See the manual for further tips.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}
  Table \ref{tab:2} lists all the variables in the model.

  \begin{table}
    \caption{Variable Descriptions}
    \label{tab:2}
    \centering
      \begin{tabular}{>{\itshape}ll}
        \toprule
        \upshape Variables & Descriptions\\\midrule
        ln(wage) & log of wage\\
        educ & years of education\\
        black & 1 if black and 0 if not\\
        hisp & 1 if hispanic and 0 if not\\
        exper & years of experience\\
        exper$^{2$} & years of experience squared\\
        married & 1 if married and 0 if not\\
        union & 1 if belongs to a union and 0 if not\\\bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: tidier table]

If you want the tabular to be inline, as the colon preceding it suggests, don't use `table` at all. You can get a caption using the `caption` package or similar.

Comment: In `ln(wage)`, "ln" and the parentheses should probably be typeset in upright rather than *italic* mode. In `exper$^{2$}`, the ordering of the the final `$` and `}` items need to reversed.